# Warning: Trigger created with compilation error

Tags: oracle, triggers, warnings

I have two tables, seat_allocation and programme_code. I want to create a trigger for checking if the number of entries into the seat_allocation are equal to the max_seats(column in programm_code table) for that prog_code(column in programme_code table). This is my code:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger seats_full
  2  before insert on seat_allocation
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5  cnt programme_code.max_seats%type;
  6  max programme_code.max_seats%type;
  7  begin
  8  select count(*) into cnt from seat_allocation where prog_code=(select prog_code from programme_code where prog_code = :NEW.prog_code);
  9  select max_seats into max from programme_code where prog_code=(select prog_code from programme_code where prog_code = :NEW.prog_code);
 10  if max=cnt then
 11  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-21000,'No vacant seats available');
 12  end if;
 13  end;
 14  /
```

It gives Warning:Trigger created with compilation error. Can you please help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: A helpful tip: If you plan on compiling code from the command line, after you compile an object, if it has errors, you can use the `show errors;` command to see the errors that caused the object fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Variable name can'be `MAX`, it is reserved for the function with the same name. Change it to e.g. `v_max_seats`.

---

Apart from that, it seems that you're selecting from the `seat_allocation` table (line #8), while the trigger fires on insert on the same table. It'll cause the *mutating table* error so - you'll have to *do something*. Nowadays, it is a **compound trigger** that fixes that. If your database version doesn't support it, you'll use a package. There are examples on the Internet.

---

Also, why using a subquery? What's wrong with e.g.

```
select max_seats into v_max_seats from programme_code where prog_code = :new.prog_code
```

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks, I will try something. Thanks for the  help!